# ¿Como utilizar la segmentacion de url en asp.net mvc?

Tags: php, c#, asp.net-mvc, codeigniter-3

buenas tengo la siguiente duda,
quiero saber como puedo trabajar con la url, a lo que me refiero es a lo siguiente, en PHP/Codeigniter, se trabajaba de esta manera.

```
//URL= https://localhost/algo

<?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=='algo') {?>
//se carga el script a usar en esa vista
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>js/algo.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

esto lo hago en el masterpage.
lo que quiero en realidad es cargar una script o estilo dependiendo de la vista que me encuentre para no cargar librerias que no usare
como podria hacer algo asi, en asp.net mvc es posible?

Comment: Lo que quieres es: ¿Cómo personalizar las rutas de tus controladores en MVC?

Comment: lo que quiero en realidad es cargar una script o estilo dependiendo de la vista que me encuentre para no cargar librerias que no usare.

Answer (score 2):

lo pude solucionar de esta forma.

```
@if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath == "/Trabajador")
{
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jsEQ")
}
```

lo que hace Request.Url.AbsolutePath es devolver la parte restante fuera del url base.

Answer (score 0):

Bien, lo que puedes hacer es crear una carpeta en tu proyecto, nombremosla **Shared**, en esta nueva sección puedes crear Views/Scripts que luego puedes implementar/compartir con todas las vistas que tú quieras sin necesidad de escribir siempre lo mismo.

Por ejemplo:

Carpeta **Shared** | *_Vista1.cshtml*

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatable")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatable.default")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatable.buttons")
```

U otro ejemplo *_Selector.cshtml* :

```
<div class="form-group">
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Hasta")
            <input id="hasta" type="text" name="hasta" data-provide="datepicker" class="form-control" placeholder="Hasta" value="@ViewBag.Hasta.ToShortDateString()" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Ahora en tu View sólo llamas a estas vistas por medio del atributo `section Script` y `Html.Partial` (Html Helpers) al final de tu vista (si son Scripts) y en caso de que sea Visualización de contenido lo colocas donde quieras.

**Script:**

```
@section scripts
{
 @Html.Partial("_Vista1")
}
```

**Contenido:**

```
@section content
{
    @Html.Partial("_Selector")
    @Styles.Render("~/content/bootstrap-multiselect")
}
```

Espero haberte dado una mano.

Un saludo, comenta cualquier inquietud.